# Accounting for space between character search

Tags: character, counting

Im having issues with my code. Its been a few years since I last wrote a even a basic program. My current issue is my program is supposed to count the number of characters entered by the user and return the count of a single char also entered by the user. Where am I going wrong at? I know it has to do with the space between words. Probably a noob mistake. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>

using namespace std;

int numTimesAppear(char *mystring, char ch)//numTimes Appear function
{
int i;
int count=0;

for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    if (mystring[i] == ch)
        count++;
}
return count;

}




int main()
{
char str[100];
char ch;
int nooftimes;

cout << ("Enter a string of characters:") << endl;
cin >> str;

cout << ("Enter a character to count:") << endl;
cin >> ch;

cout << numTimesAppear(str, ch);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: For example if I enter the words Hello World as my string and count how many o there are it should return 2.

Comment: couldn't `i < 100` be a problem?

Comment: what should it be?

Comment: issue with array?